# Find the operators

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Assume you are using a basic calculator and press these numbers in order. Replace each question mark with plus, minus, multiply and divide may be used, but no sign should be used more than once. In which order must they be used?

```
3?2?1?4?3=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is

> 3 x 2 + 1 - 4 / 3 = 1

Comment: Whoops! Undeleted mine to realize that you've posted it already. I'll re-delete mine :)

Comment: Sorry about that! Good answer on your part as well! :)

Comment: Sorry, it says I can only accept your answer in eight mintutes

Comment: Haha that's okay, I can be patient! I like the 15 minute rule :)